# C/C++ Can not run a for loop in a for loop

Tags: c++, c, dev-c++

here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
/*
CALCULATING INVERSE OF A MATRIX
*/
int main(){

    int matris[3][3];
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    for(i; i<3;i++){

        for(j;j<3;j++){

            scanf("%d", &matris[i][j]);                         
        }
        printf("%d", matris[i][j]);         
    }    
}
```

I know its basic but i have a trouble with it, my compiler is Dev-C++ and my OS is windows 10 by the way, when i run this code and press the 1,2,3 that's the only output that i can see.

```
1
2
3
0430
--------------------------------
Process exited after 2.351 seconds with return value 1
```

I don't know where is my mistake, thanks for help

**EDIT**

I've edited the code as:

```
int main(){

    int matris[3][3];
    int i,j;
    for(i = 0; i<3; i++){
        for (j=0;j<3;j++){
            scanf("%d", &matris);
        }
    }

    for(i = 0; i<3; i++){

        for (j=0;j<3;j++){

            printf("%d ", matris);
        }
    }

}
```

But still i can not see the proper output.

Output:

```
1
2   
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
6487536 6487536 6487536 6487536 6487536 6487536 6487536 6487536 6487536
```

But of course the expected output is something like 3x3 matrix and integers 1 to 9

Comment: What is the output you were expecting?

Comment: Consider where you print the value, and what `j` is in that case.

Comment: You are accessing the array out of bounds. After the inner for loop `j` is 3 and you are printing `matrix[i][3]`. That's called undefined behavior and strange things can happen.

Comment: After the first inner loop, `j == 3`. You have to reset it every time, like `for (j=0; ...`. That's what the initializer part is of `for` _for_.

Comment: NB. You should learn to use your debugger - this would be easy to find by stepping through to the second iteration of the inner loop.

Comment: What is the expected output ? code scans for 3 integers, then print (uninitialized) matris[0][3], than it will exit, since the 2nd (and any future invocation) of the j loop does not initialize j=0. Try (1) fix the 'for' statements (for j=0 ; j<3 ; j++), and also (for i=0 i<3 ; i++) (2) fix the print indices

Comment: expecting output were of course "1 2 3" and i'd expect to continue. I don't know why it stopped to working, what should i do?

Comment: when i changed my inner loop as i=0 and i++, then output became "013" and stopped again

Comment: @M.Utku Why don't you simply 1) Read all of the input *first*, then 2) Output the matrix second?  The issue is that you're trying to do two things at once, and you're getting confused.  There is nothing wrong with having a second set of `for` loops to output the information.

Comment: Also, what language are you using C or C++?  They are two different languages, i.e. there is no such language as `C/C++`.  If it's C++, why are you using non type-safe input and output routines (`scanf` and `printf`) instead of typesafe functions (`cin`, `cout`)?  Why are your loop counters declared with variables outside of the loop instead of `for (int i = 0; ...);`?

Answer (score 1):

You can, but you need to set j to an initial value before it goes into the loop for every value of i
right now it just goes once through the j loop and next time it goes there it sees that j is > then 3 so it just skips it

Answer (score 0):

Don't to this:

```
for(i = 0; i<3; i++){
    for (j=0;j<3;j++){
        scanf("%d", &matris);
    }
}

for(i = 0; i<3; i++){
    for (j=0;j<3;j++){
        printf("%d ", matris);
    }
}
```

Do this instead:

```
for(i = 0; i<3; i++){
    for (j=0;j<3;j++){
        scanf("%d", matris[i]+j);
    }
}

for(i = 0; i<3; i++){
    for (j=0;j<3;j++){
        printf("%d ", matris[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: dev c++ raises this error "[Error] 'for' loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 or C11 mode"

Comment: @M.Utku well. use compiler flags to switch to C99 or C11 mode, it's 2019 -- there's no point using outdated compilers anymore. if you tell me what compiler do you use, i might be able to help to find the correct compiler flags. Something like `-std=c++11` or `-std=c99` might help.

Comment: i've just downloaded dev c++ but it raises some errors while i was compiling then i erased it and downloaded another dev c++. I was having no problem until today but i don't know why it shows me now

Comment: @M.Utku So you erased a compiler from your system because you had compiler errors??

Comment: @M.Utku Please, see the updated answer, this should work everywhere.

Comment: i've done. Now program doesn't stop working but output is only 0. I want to see the entire matrix

Comment: Please, see my another answer. it works, there are problems, but you should be able to fix that.

Comment: @M.Utku I've edited the answer. Your last modifications removed indices `i` and `j` -- this should be fixed. See the code above.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the result:

```
$ g++ m.cpp
$ ./a.out
1
2
3
04
5
6
41954727
8
9
32764
```

And here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
/*
CALCULATING INVERSE OF A MATRIX
*/
int main(){

    int matris[3][3];
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    for(i=0; i<3;i++){

        for(j=0;j<3;j++){

            scanf("%d", &matris[i][j]);
        }
        printf("%d", matris[i][j]);
    }
}
```

It works as it should, however, I'd advise against using `printf("%d", matris[i][j]);` outside of `j` loop, because `j` is equal to `3` and this is kind of undefined behaviour.